# Android: EditText inside ScrollView : hide keyboard generates strange scrolling

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I have this layout example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="#FFF880"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scroll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/action_bar_layout">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/emotion"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edit"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                            android:singleLine="false"
                            android:text="On sait depuis longtemps "
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/photo"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="350dp"
                            android:background="#EE00FF">

                        </FrameLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </ScrollView>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/action_bar_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="#990000"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                </FrameLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my sample Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edittext);
        final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        final EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

        // Setup scrollview
        scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                final int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        // Hide keyboard
                        UIUtils.hideKeyboard(edittext, EditTextActivity.this);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

public static void hideKeyboard(View view, Activity activity) {
        if (view != null) {
            view.clearFocus();
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.
                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I would like the same behavior like Facebook new post: when you want to scroll the keyboard disappears automatically.

But in my case, there is a strange behavior when you want to scroll when the keyboard has been hide.

Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/action_bar_layout"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:background="#FFF880"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            </FrameLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/emotion"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edit"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                            android:singleLine="false"
                            android:text="On sait depuis longtemps "
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/photo"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="350dp"
                            android:background="#EE00FF">

                        </FrameLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/action_bar_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:background="#990000"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    </FrameLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Try this hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: No Risbhabh! The framelyout "action_bar_layout" must be always present in bottom

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding keyboard on scroll ,you can hide keyboard on outsidetouch of edit text

Make the parent view(content view of your activity) clickable and focusable by adding the following attributes

```
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Implement a hideKeyboard() method

```
    public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

and set the onFocusChangeListener of your edittext.

```
    edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                hideKeyboard(v);
            }
        }
    });
```

or if you want to hide on scroll then you can add on touch listner for your main view instead of scroll view

```
findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setOnTouchListener(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` on main container